Icon Mismatch on First Page Load in Next.js Theme Switch Component
On first load of the page from a new browser / icognito mode it shows two sun icons when you toggle theme instead of a sun and a moon, after i refresh it works.
`import { Switch } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { SunIcon } from "../Images/SunIcon";
import { MoonIcon } from "../Images/MoonIcon";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const ThemeSwitch = () => {
  const { theme, setTheme, resolvedTheme } = useTheme();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) {
    return null;
  }

  const isDarkMode = theme === "dark" || resolvedTheme === "dark";

  return (
    <Switch
      checked={isDarkMode}
      size="lg"
      color="success"
      startContent={<SunIcon />}
      endContent={isDarkMode ? <MoonIcon /> : <SunIcon />}
      onChange={() => setTheme(isDarkMode ? "light" : "dark")}
    >
      <span className="hidden md:inline"> Dark mode</span>
    </Switch>
  );
};
`

This is how it behaves on first load
I tried to use useEffect to delay rendering so it can match the theme, but the issuse persist and i don't really know what to do. Also i don't know why the theme doesen't change when i change system theme
Update: ThemeProvider code from next-themes wrapping the layout
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { Navbar } from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import { NetworkProvider } from "./contexts/NetworkContext";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "title",
  description: "description",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <NetworkProvider>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <ThemeProvider
            attribute="class"
            defaultTheme="system"
            enableSystem={true}
          >
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <div className="h-[100px] w-full"></div>
            <div className="flex flex-col text-white w-full items-center justify-center">
              {children}
            </div>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </NetworkProvider>
    </html>
  );
}

And this is the console.log i don't know why it's logged 2 times
console.log

Please update the question by adding code for <ThemeProvider>, what props are passed to it. Also add console.logs for theme, resolvedTheme & isDarkMode before return keyword.

Thank you for answer, the  is from next-themes i updated the post.

Problem :


On first load of the page from a new browser / icognito mode it shows two sun icons when you toggle theme instead of a sun and a moon, after i refresh it works.
the console.log i don't know why it's logged 2 times


Possible Cause :


startContent={<SunIcon />} startContent is icon on left side of switch, this value is rendered when theme light (switch selected false), but you also have passed endContent={isDarkMode ? <MoonIcon /> : <SunIcon />} this adds <SunIcon /> icon in the end part of the switch when isDarkMode false (light), hence two sun icons & also there is no prop checked in Switch component of NextUI.
nextjs strict mode is enabled by default


Solution :
Only pass one Icon in each prop :
   startContent={<SunIcon />}
   endContent={<MoonIcon />}

Replace :
checked={isDarkMode}

to
isSelected={isDarkMode}

Improvement :
Replace :
const isDarkMode = theme === "dark" || resolvedTheme === "dark";

to
const isDarkMode = useMemo(() => resolvedTheme === "dark", [resolvedTheme]);

This will reduce unecessary re-renders & calculation of isDarkMode value. Also as you have set defaultTheme="system" enableSystem={true}, resolvedTheme returns value "dark" or "light".
Optional :
When mounted is false, instead of returning null you can return Spinner this will reduce Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) when Switch will get mounted.


Strict Mode is development mode only feature for highlighting potential problems in an application. Thats why you see console.logs twice.

To disable :
next.config.js :
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}


Please Read :

Switch with Icons Example : https://nextui.org/docs/components/switch#with-icons
When Switch is ON/OFF Example : https://nextui.org/docs/components/switch#controlled
Switch Props : https://nextui.org/docs/components/switch#switch-props
reactStrictMode : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode
Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) : https://web.dev/articles/cls
resolvedTheme value : https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes?tab=readme-ov-file#usetheme-1:~:text=theme%20switching%20UI-,resolvedTheme,-%3A%20If%20enableSystem%20is


If this answer was solved your problem then mark it as solution. If this answer was very helpful then you may upvote. If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer as necessary)

